# Line of no data runs down map

Tags: cartopy

I am currently plotting precipitation from a netcdf dataset. When I plot my data a line of no data appears which isn't there is a different plot I made. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np

from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5)) 

dataset = netcdf_dataset(datapath_1 +              
'/PREC.E_2000_CAM5_1850aero.cam.mean.40-100.nc')            

precip = dataset.variables['PREC'][0, :, :]
lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())

ax.contourf(lons, lats, precip, 100, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())


ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

and here is the output map:
[output map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YTZv.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a cyclic point to your data array and longitude coordinate (https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.16/cartopy/util/util.html#cartopy.util.add_cyclic_point). Your example modified to do this (but not tested because we don't have your input data):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np

from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point

dataset = netcdf_dataset(datapath_1 +
                         '/PREC.E_2000_CAM5_1850aero.cam.mean.40-100.nc')
precip = dataset.variables['PREC'][0, :, :]
lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]

precip_c, lons_c = add_cyclic_point(precip, coord=lons)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
ax.contourf(lons_c, lats, precip_c, 100, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```